# Bitstamp.net API Realtime

Tags: bitstamp

I am testing out the BitMap API, and my get function to get the ticker looks something like this

```
 r = requests.get("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/", proxies=self.proxydict)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return r.json()
        else:
            r.raise_for_status()
```

However, I notice the "last" price it returns is always a little different than the one shown here (https://www.bitstamp.net/) Is the API realtime? Or is it lagging behind the actual price.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the BitMap API? Am I correct in assuming you are talking about BitStamp's own API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this is due to the fact that prices can change very rapidly if many orders are executed in a short period of time.

In my tests both prices are the same, and none seem to lag after the other.